# Gatsby-plugin-image with programmatically created pages issue

Tags: graphql, gatsby, programmatically-created

I'm creating pages programmatically in gatsby from MD files. the issues I'm having is I'm using the  from gatsby-plugin-image to pull the image from the frontmatter of said MD file when the page loads the img is not rendered and i get and error gatsby-plugin-image] Missing image prop

this is the file and graphql set up

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import {Button, Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import "../styles/main.scss";

const ProductPage = ({ data }) => {
  const post = data.markdownRemark;
  const image = getImage(post.image)
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <Card>
          <GatsbyImage
            className="card-image-top"
            src={image}
            alt={post.description}
            placeholder="blurred"
            width={500}
            layout="constraint"
          />
          <CardTitle>{post.frontmatter.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardBody>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
            <Button 
             className="btn btn-outline-secondary float-right" color="light">Buy</Button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        description
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(
              width: 500
              placeholder: BLURRED
              formats: [AUTO]
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default ProductPage;
```

I have tried a few different props such as changing

src={post.frontmatter.image} to src={image},

and changing

const image = getImage(post.image) to   const image = getImage(post.frontmatter.image)

as you can see the title works fine so it has to be an issue with the image.

also when I use the same query in graphiql it does return the image.

Comment: and again .... `console.log(data);` (`post` or `image`) before return JSX? is it hard to start from checking data/props/args?

Comment: why not `data`? why derivatives??????? ... update question

Comment: so console.log(image) returns undefined but console.log(post) returns {
  html: '<p>hello there. this is it.</p>',
  frontmatter: {
    title: 'My tattoos dont like you either',
    description: "well it's true they don't",
    image: { childImageSharp: [Object] }
  }
}

Comment: `const image = getImage(post.frontmatter.image); console.log(image);` ... plus read image plugin docs again ... about `<GatsbyImage />` props/args ... error is exactly about that !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your image belongs to the `frontmatter`, so according to your trials, you've never tried:

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import {Button, Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import "../styles/main.scss";

const ProductPage = ({ data }) => {
  const post = data.markdownRemark;
  const image = getImage(post.image)
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <Card>
          <GatsbyImage
            className="card-image-top"
            src={post.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData}
            alt={post.description}
            placeholder="blurred"
            width={500}
            layout="constraint"
          />
          <CardTitle>{post.frontmatter.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardBody>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
            <Button 
             className="btn btn-outline-secondary float-right" color="light">Buy</Button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        description
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(
              width: 500
              placeholder: BLURRED
              formats: [AUTO]
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default ProductPage;
```

Notice the nesting in `post.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData`

Comment: Thank you very much I actually need to close this out I realized the issue with it was I was calling the image with "SRC" whichi is used for the <StaticImage> with the <GatsbyImage> i should have been using "image" to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import {Button, Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import "../styles/main.scss";

const ProductPage = ({ data }) => {
  const post = data.markdownRemark;
  const image = getImage(post.image)
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <Card>
          <GatsbyImage
            className="card-image-top"
            src={post.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} <= should be using "IMAGE" not "SRC" SRC is used for <StaticImage> <GatsbyImage> should use "IMAGE" to call it.
            alt={post.description}
            placeholder="blurred"
            width={500}
            layout="constraint"
          />
          <CardTitle>{post.frontmatter.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardBody>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
            <Button 
             className="btn btn-outline-secondary float-right" color="light">Buy</Button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```